# Is $b\mid a$ standard notation for $b$ divides $a$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, notation, divisibility

Is there a standard way of writing **$a$ is divisible by $b$** in mathematical notation?

From what I've search it seems that writing $a \equiv 0 \pmod b$ is one way? But also you can write $b \mid a$ as well (the middle character is a pipe)? And sometimes that pipe is replaced by $3$ vertical dots?

Or is there a way of writing **$a$ is a multiple of $b$** which I think means the same thing?

EDIT: thanks for the answers, is there a way to extend this and write something like: $b \mid a$ when $a = k$

Comment: I usually use $|$

Comment: The standard is $b\mid a$ whic is typeset "b \mid a" in TeX

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols

Comment: @pedja, thanks but that article lists both options

Comment: @AndreaMori, why mid? Is it short for something?

Comment: @PeterPhipps The spacing is different, compare $A|B$, $A\mid B$, $A\vert B$, $A\lvert B$ and $A\rvert B$ (edit: there actually are differences there in some fonts, even if those are not visible here).

Comment: @PeterPhipps I've found it: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/498/mid-vert-lvert-rvert

Comment: d|A means d divides A.

Answer (score 31):

I have seen the following:

- $b \mid a$ that is with $\LaTeX$ `\mid`
- $a = 0 \mod b$ that is with $\LaTeX$ `\mod`
- $a = 0 \pmod b$ that is with $\LaTeX$ `\pmod`
- $a \bmod b = 0$ that is with $\LaTeX$ `\bmod`
- $a \equiv 0\ (b)$
- $a \equiv_{b} 0$

and of course there is

- $a = bk$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$

Choose whatever suits you (and your friends or readers) best!

Comment: Thanks for the list, `a mod b = 0` makes the most sense to me. But b|a seems more for use in commentary?

Comment: It depends on so many things that I can't tell you this or that way. For me there are three important factors: how often will I use it (more often means less symbols), do I need to use it "in chains" like $a = b = c = d \pmod n$ and do I need to use different $n$-s, e.g. $a \equiv_3 b \equiv_5 c \equiv_7 d$ (which may be confusing but _sometimes_ is helpful). Still, the most important criterion of all is readability.

Answer (score 23):

Alexander Merkurjev taught  me a long time ago  the ingenious Russian notation  $6 \vdots 2$, which I immediately adopted .
It  pleasantly "rhymes" with  the  equivalent $(6)\subset (2)$

Comment: I wonder if you are the unique non-Russian who uses that notation. I didn't think it is used in public outside of Russia (or at least Eastern Europe).

Comment: We use it in Romania too!

Comment: @Victor I recently attended a lecture in the US aimed at undergraduates and the lecturer used this notation without being aware that it is practically unknown here.  The lecturer was Romanian.

Answer (score 12):

There is also " $a \in b\mathbb Z$ ".

Answer (score 7):

I often write that as `b divides a`

**Notation:**

$$b \mid a$$

Comment: This is the standard way, in the specific meaning of compliance to international standards: ISO 80000-2, clause 2.7-17. Note that the vertical bar character used there is normatively identified as U+2223 DIVIDES (∣), note the common U+007C VERTICAL LINE (|) that we enter directly on a keyboard. It is of course possible to express the same thing using a congruence notation, but only for integers (not e.g. for polynomials).

Answer (score 5):

- **Definition:** Integer $n$ *is a divisible by* an integer $d$, when $\exists k \in \mathbb{Z}, n=d\times k$.
- **Notation:** $d \mid n$
- **Synonymous:**
- $n$ is a multiple of $d$.
- $d$ is a factor of $n$
- $d$ is a divisor of $n$
- $d$ divides $n$

Answer (score 2):

$a \equiv 0 \mod b$ and $b \mid a$ are both common, and their use depends on the context.  Given a choice, I use the latter more than the former.

There are others such as $\text{lcm}(a,b)=a$ or $\text{hcf}(a,b)=b$ [or perhaps $\text{gcd}(a,b)=b$ if you prefer] which might also be used when more suitable for the context.

Answer (score 0):

COMMENT.- A notation forget in this page is $a\mid\mid b$ which is pertinent many times, very useful really, in number theory. It is used when  a power of a prime, say $p^n$ is the maximal power that divides an integer $M$.
In other words
$$p^n\mid\mid M\iff p^n\mid M \text{  but } p^{n+1}\nmid M$$