# How to prove that $2^{x+2} | 3^{2^x} - 1$ is true for all natural x greater than zero

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Actually, I don't know it's true or not. I just make observation and write simple python script that checked this for x belongs to [1, 50] and it's alright. Can somebody tell it is true or not and if it is true, how I can prove this?

Comment: You'll have to define the notation - it is not standard. What does the $3^{2^x}-1:2^x$ mean?

Comment: I change the notation, sorry for misleading :)

Comment: Induction works. Here's a hint:$$3^{2^x} - 1 = (3^{2^{x-1}})^2 - 1 = (3^{2^{x-1}} - 1)(3^{2^{x-1}} + 1).$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Today I learned of this [notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/135385/463578)